# Redirecionar usuário não autorizado Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Quando uma página que está com o `middleware auth` tenta ser acessada por um usuário não autenticado, o Laravel redireciona ele para a rota 'login'. Como mudar isso para que ele redirecione para outra rota?

Answer (score 4):

Dentro de seu projeto no caminho `app/Http/Middleware` haverá um arquivo chamado `Authenticate.php`.

Na função `redirectTo()` você deve alterar a linha do retorno da função, com a rota que deseja.

Por exemplo, você deseja mudar a rota de `login` para `register`.
Trocaremos:

```
protected function redirectTo($request){
    if (! $request->expectsJson()) {
        return route('login');
    }
}
```

Por:

```
protected function redirectTo($request){
    if (! $request->expectsJson()) {
        return route('register');
    }
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]